# Curve is zero iff integral of "scalar product" with respect to all other curves is zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

Let $ X $ be a Banach space and let $ \omega\colon X\times X\to \mathbb R $ be a continuous bilinear form on $ X $. Let $ \gamma\colon \left[t_1,t_2\right]\to X $ be a curve such that $ \gamma(t_1) = q_1\in X $ and $ \gamma(t_2) = q_2\in X $.

Suppose that
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\omega(\gamma(t),\eta(t))\,\mathrm dt = 0
$$
for all curves $ \eta\colon \left[t_1,t_2\right]\to X $ such that $ \eta(t_1) = 0 = \eta(t_2) $.

Is it the case that $ \gamma(t) = 0 $ for all $ t $s?

Comment: "Curve" by universally-accepted definition means a continuous map on a real interval (or the image of that map). So it isn't necessary to add that requirement.

Comment: Consider $X = \Bbb R^2, \gamma : [0,1] \to \Bbb R^2 : t \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}0\\t\end{bmatrix}$ and $$\omega(v,w) = v^T\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}w$$

Comment: Whops, I forgot to require $ \omega $ to be positive definite (or at least non-degenerate).

Comment: If you didn't require that $\eta$ be $0$ at its endpoints, then the answer would be obvious: just let $\eta = \gamma$ and your requirement that $\omega$ is non-degenerate means $\gamma$ has to be $0$. As it is, you might consider for each $\epsilon > 0$, an $\eta_\epsilon$ that goes from $0$ to $\gamma(t_1+\epsilon)$ on $[t_1, t_1 + \epsilon]$. matches $\gamma$ until $t_2-\epsilon$, then heads back to $0$.